# How can I set the flag FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS for an fstream object?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, fstream

How can I set the flag FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS for an fstream object?

You can set most flags with fstream, but it seems like this one is not availble.  You can read about the flag [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this sort thing in the past but it's been a while so I'm not sure I have it right.

Not well documented, but in vs2008, fstream takes a FILE object as a constructor.  You can create a FILE object from a file id with _fdopen().  You can get a file id from an os handle using _open_osfhandle.

So I think it's like:

```
int id = _open_osfhandle(CreateFile(..., FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS...));
fstream f = new fstream(_fdopen(id));
```